# RTSP ip camera connection or vlc image processing in C#

Tags: c#, rtsp, libvlcsharp

I'm working on a project. I need to connect RTSP ip camera for this project. I made the RTSP connection using the vlc plugin but for this project, I have to do visual processing on this publication. and I guess vlc plugin doesn't support bitmap class, I need convert the image from vlc plugin to bitmap class or a different type of RTSP connection

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this sample https://github.com/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/PreviewThumbnailExtractor.Skia

This sample grabs frame from a video source, and saves the image using SkiaSharp. But the result will be really slow, and you won't be able to analyze your images in real time.

LibVLCSharp/libvlc is probably not the best way to do that.